# How to use mimeType Assert with VichUploader?

Tags: symfony, assert, vichuploaderbundle

This assert is passing Symfony's form validation when uploading any file with [VichUploaderBundle](http://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle):

```
/**
 * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="product_media", fileNameProperty="path")
 * @Assert\File(
 *     mimeTypes = {"image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png", "video/mp4", "video/quicktime", "video/avi"},
 *     mimeTypesMessage = "Wrong file type (jpg,gif,png,mp4,mov,avi)"
 * )
 * @var File $pathFile
 */
protected $pathFile;
```

I cannot see what the problem is with the assert. How can I validate file types with VichUploader?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use validation callback to solve this issue.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\Repository\EntityRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="entity")
 * @Assert\Callback(methods={"validate"})
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 */
class Entity
{
    /**
     * @Assert\File(maxSize="10M")
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="files", fileNameProperty="fileName")
     *
     * @var File $file
     */
    protected $file;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, name="file_name", nullable=true)
     *
     * @var string $fileName
     */
    protected $fileName;

...

    /**
     * @param ExecutionContextInterface $context
     */
    public function validate(ExecutionContextInterface $context)
    {
        if (! in_array($this->file->getMimeType(), array(
            'image/jpeg',
            'image/gif',
            'image/png',
            'video/mp4',
            'video/quicktime',
            'video/avi',
        ))) {
            $context
                ->buildViolation('Wrong file type (jpg,gif,png,mp4,mov,avi)')
                ->atPath('fileName')
                ->addViolation()
            ;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The validation silently fails on symfony 2.7

Comment: In newer versions of Symfony, the Callback annotation has to be added to the methods doc block rather than the class's: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html#configuration

Comment: Note I needed to add the `@Assert\Callback` annotation for the `validate()` function for this to work.  See: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html#configuration

Answer (score 7):

For Symfony 4.0 you'll need to import the Validator component

```
composer require validator
```

Now in your Entity class you can use the @Assert annotation.

```
// src/Entity/Author.php

// ...
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class Author
{
    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    public $name;
}
```

You might need to add some configuration in your config/packages/framework.yaml file. Anyway, all this is perfectly explained on the official Symfony documentation.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html

To check the mime type you'll need to use the File constraint http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/File.html

Here is a working exemple

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 * @var string
 */
private $cvFilename;

/**
 * @Assert\File(
 *     maxSize = "2048k",
 *     mimeTypes = {"application/pdf", "application/x-pdf"},
 *     mimeTypesMessage = "Please upload a valid PDF"
 * )
 * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="cv", fileNameProperty="cvFilename")
 * @var File
 */
private $cvFile;
```

Now it's true that there is a mime and size option inside the @Vich\UploadableField anotation as described here https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/usage.md#step-2-link-the-upload-mapping-to-an-entity
but I couldn't get this to work.

The @Assert annotation will generate Forms errors, that you can retrieve them in Twig to give a feedback.

The key is to use : `form_errors(candidature_form.cvFile)`

here is a working example :

```
 {% set error_flag = form_errors(candidature_form.cvFile) %}

        <label class=" {% if error_flag %}has-error{% endif %}">
            Curriculum Vitae (PDF)
        </label>
        {{ form_widget(candidature_form.cvFile) }}
        {% if error_flag %}
            <div class="has-error">
                {{ form_errors(candidature_form.cvFile) }}
            </div>
        {% endif %}
```

Comment: Is it possible to i18n the messages set in annotations? If not, this solution is not so great...

Comment: I think it's ok. I haven't test it though https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/translations.html

Answer (score 2):

For Symfony 4.x, this solution not working. i don't know why assert or event validator never call ...

I've find this solution : [Validation doesn't work on relation fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45191816/validation-doesnt-work-on-relation-fields)

```
         use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\File;
        /* ... */
        ->add('ba_file', VichFileType::class, [
                'label' => 'Bon d\'adhésion (PDF file)',
                'required' => false,
                'constraints' => [
                    new File([
                        'maxSize' => '5M',
                        'mimeTypes' => [
                            'image/jpeg',
                            'image/gif',
                            'image/png',
                        ]
                    ])
                ]
            ])
```

Comment: Have you been able to find out why this wasn't working as expected with @assert/Valid ?

Answer (score 1):

For **Symfony 3.0+**, only 2 things need to be done:

- Add use statement to import *ExecutionContextInterface*.
- The *callback annotation* has to be added directly to the method/function instead of the class.

  ```
  use Symfony\Component\Validator\Context\ExecutionContextInterface;

  /**
  * @Assert\File(maxSize="2M")
  * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="profile_image", fileNameProperty="avatar")
  * @var File
  */
  private $imageFile;

  /**
  * @ORM\Column(length=255, nullable=true)
  * @var string $avatar
  */
  protected $avatar;

  /**
  * @Assert\Callback
  * @param ExecutionContextInterface $context
  */
  public function validate(ExecutionContextInterface $context, $payload)
  {
     // do your own validation
     if (! in_array($this->imageFile->getMimeType(), array(
         'image/jpeg',
         'image/gif',
         'image/png'
  ))) {
      $context
          ->buildViolation('Wrong file type (only jpg,gif,png allowed)')
          ->atPath('imageFile')
          ->addViolation();
     }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Symfony 6 - PHP 8:

Entity class:

```
#[Vich\UploadableField(mapping: 'avatars', fileNameProperty: 'avatarName')]
#[Assert\File(maxSize: '1024k', mimeTypes: ['image/jpeg', 'image/png'])]
private ?File $avatarFile = null;
```

FormType class:

```
 'attr' => [
   'accept' => 'image/jpeg, image/png',
 ],
 'constraints' => [
    new Assert\File([
       'maxSize' => '1024k',
       'mimeTypes' => ['image/jpeg', 'image/png'],
    ]),
 ],
```